# Vue.js. Best practices with initialization-only data binding?

Tags: vue.js, initialization

I have this component which is managed by Bootstrap, specifically one of those nav-tabs widgets where, as you click Bootstrap shows and hides.

Bootstrap keeps track of which item was clicked on using the `.active` class.  And, in Vue, I was to initialize a certain nav as being active on page load.  But, once that's done, I want Vue leave the `.active` class management entirely up to Bootstrap.

```
<template>
<li class="nav-item"  v-if="toshow">
    <a class="nav-link" v-bind:id="'nav_' + link" 
    :class="{ active: isActive }" :aria-expanded="isActive"
    v-bind:href="'#'+link" data-toggle="tab" @click="onclick">
        {{label_}}
        <span v-if="badge" class="badge" :class="badge_level">{{badge}}</span>
        <span v-if="dynamic_badge" class="badge" :class="badge_level" >{{badge_value}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
</template>
```

At page load time, each component checks against Vuex and figures out if its `id` is in `this.$store.state.active_tab` - that's what sets `.active`.

```
    ,isActive: function(){

      //active_tab is where I specify which tab should be active
      //at first
      var res = this.link === this.$store.state.active_tab;

      return res;

    },
```

`v-once` is not a good fit, because the only thing I want to disable is the computation of `.active` (the *badge children* need to be updated live).

The component works, kinda.  I think mostly because `this.$store.state.active_tab`'s value does not mutate so Vue doesn't re-render.  But it seems brittle at best.

What are best practices for using Vue to only set the **initial** values of certain variables, and then relinquishing control, without using `v-once`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just access the `a.nav-link` element and add the `.active` class to its `classList` directly.

You can add a `ref` attribute to the `a.nav-lank` element link so:

```
<a class="nav-link" ref="link" ...>
  ...
</a>
```

And then add the `.active` class in the `mounted` hook:

```
mounted() {
  if (this.link === this.$store.state.active_tab) {
    this.$refs.link.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

Comment: but... wouldn't Vue go back and grab `data.isActive` again to populate `.active`, as soon as it wanted to re-render?  In my example, I think I can live with that.  But, suppose the component had another bound attribute/value, say, `{{record_count}}` that was expected to be kept live and synched.  If the underlying data or store source for `record_count` was updated, then the component would be re-render for `record_count`, which is good.  But `active` would **also** be updated again as per `data.isActive`, would it not?

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. You want to set the `active` class initially, but not bind it. See my updated answer

Comment: nice.  so, basically, avoid binding for this type of use case and initialize stuff in `mounted`.  makes sense.